# How to search a related property of a model via search view model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, mvvm, viewmodel

I am new to MVC and view models.I have trouble generating a LINQ search query on a related property of my search model. Here is my model of MaterialRequestMaster in domain layer:

```cs
public class MaterialRequestMaster : BaseDomain<long> 
{
    public string RequestCode { get; private set; }
    public int UserId { get; private set; }
    public GlobalEnums.MaterialRequestStatus Status { get; set; }
    public SecurityUser User { get; private set; } //related property
}
```

and a MaterialRequestMasterSearchViewModel in application layer:

```cs
public  class MaterialRequestMasterSearchModel
{
    public string RequestCode { get; set; }
    public GlobalEnums.MaterialRequestStatus Status { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
}
```

which holds name of the user instead of the user Id ,and I have a service to make where-string of the LINQ query where gets the JSON of search parameters from view.
How do I search MaterialRequestMasters on user name field?

Comment: Hi @Kasra H. do you want to search for the MaterialRequestMasterSearchModel by UserName? But where is the UserName from? From query string/form submit you pass? Or from SecurityUser? And what is your SecurityUser?